# How does Immutable.js comparation work?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability, immutable.js

I have been using Immutable.js for some time, and just now I found out that  the comparison operator does not work how I thought.

My code is simple:

```
a = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:[1,2,3]})
b = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:[1,2,3]})
a == b // false
Immutable.is(a, b) // false
```

Is there any way to compare two of the same Immutable objects and get `true`?

Functional logic tells me they should be equal, but in JavaScript they are not.

Comment: My guess is that `[1,2,3] != [1,2,3]` in your `b` key. Try to put the same object in both, or make it two immutable lists (or whatever they call it)

Comment: don't know how `immutable` works but to make an obj comparison you need to build deep comparison function

Comment: Ah you are right! If I use `Immutable.fromJS` instead of `Immutable.Map` comparsion works fine. It is impractical for deep structures which are often changes to keep all objects inside immutable and dont forget some plain map or array.

Answer (score 3):

`a == b` essentially compares "addresses" of two objects. 
And in your code you create two distinct instances of objects and so they are always different, therefore  `a == b` is false by JavaScript specification.

As of how to compare two objects in JS, check this: 
[Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: `assert(a != b)` is expected, what about `Immutable.is`?

Comment: @Pavlo if `Immutable.is(a, b)` is really false then this is probably a bug in their implementation. Immutable.is definition is kind of fuzzy in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
  var c = [1,2,3],
      a = Immutable.Map({a:1, b: c}),
      b = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:[1,2,3]});
  c[0] = 9;

  console.log(JSON.stringify(a), JSON.stringify(b));
}());
```

The way you are creating `a` and `b` would allow you to have side effects if you retained a reference (such as `c`) to the inner array as demonstrated above.

I think the comparisons are correctly telling you that the objects are not the same.